# Probability of given group

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

[image]

Given the survey above, what is the probability that student who is subjectively in the middle class belongs to the upper middle class?

I have computed the answer as $\frac{13}{45}$ by using the conditional probability, or just from the definition of probability. I wonder whether answer is true, and if it is wrong, could you tell what is the correct approach for solving it?

Comment: any ideas for this thought experiment?

Comment: It´s correct. The number of students who are subjective middle class  are 32 and 13. The sum is the sample space. From that you select 13 ( Intersection of subjective middle class (S) and objective middle class (B)). The formula is $P(B|S)=\frac{P(B\cap S)}{P(S)}$ (Bayes Theorem).

Comment: Meta-Cheating is helpful here.  In this case, that means - what is the purpose of the problem?  I surmise that the *actual* purpose was not for you to focus on Bayes Theorem, but whether you could interpret the data in the chart by **stretching your intuition**.  Stretching your intuition is very helpful in math, especially Probability &/or Combinatorics.

Comment: @user2661923 Could you exemplify on what you mean?

Comment: Similar to what callculus commented, but without the Bayes Theorem.  My *surmise* is that the challenge of the question was for the OP to recognize that there were 32 [subjective middle class : working class] and 13 [subjective middle class : upper middle class].  My further surmise is that you were supposed to forget anything about probability that you were taught and simply attack the problem with common sense.  Your common sense would indicate that all of the chart should be ignored except the two #'s 32 and 13.  Then your common sense was supposed to give you a solution that *made sense*.